# Is it appropriate to merge duplicate unregistered users? (And if so, here's a case)

Tags: support, user-accounts

I just noticed that Ted Ersek has duplicate unregistered accounts, [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/456/ted-ersek) and [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/443/ted-ersek). As he is a valued member of the Mathematica community generally, it would be good to merge his accounts. Does it matter that he is not registered?

Comment: I would first gently encourage Ted to register (dangle a few carrots, if you will), and then we can flag for his unregistered accounts to be folded into his registered one for his and our convenience.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what's an unregistered account?  (Or, how does one register an account?)

Comment: @Brett: It is entirely possible to post questions/answers without having to go through the rigamarole of clicking the "log in" button at the top of any SE site or the one in the bottom left of any text box. One just has to specify a name, e-mail address (for identification and Gravatar purposes) and possibly a home page. See [these meta.SO](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unregistered-users) questions for some more info.

Comment: @J.M. How can one tell if an account is registered or not?  One of his accounts says "meta user" too, surely at least that one must be registered?

Comment: @Szabolcs: to use [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/456/ted-ersek) as an example, note the gray "Unregistered" bit to the right of the username... registered accounts do not have this mark, of course.

Comment: Once his account is registered, and the "duplicate" accounts flagged, merging them all together will mean that all of his questions and answers will be associated with one parent account, and his reputation will aggregate. :)

Comment: Dear @Aarthi, he has registered now http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/460/ted-ersek

Answer (score 3):

Now that he's registered, I've gone ahead and merged his unregistered child accounts into his main, registered one. :D If he has more child accounts pop up, let me know and I'll merge them all into the main account.

[image: ted]